# Adding contextual sub-menu to Finder using Services

Tags: xcode, macos, contextmenu, finder

I would like to create sub menus within the contextual menu in Finder.  A small prototype application I have that uses the Services API...

```
#import "servicesAppDelegate.h"

@implementation servicesAppDelegate

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
  [NSApp setServicesProvider:self];
  NSUpdateDynamicServices();
}

- (void)handleServices:(NSPasteboard *)pboard
              userData:(NSString *)userData 
                 error:(NSString **)error
{
    if([[pboard types] containsObject:NSFilenamesPboardType])
    {
      NSArray* fileArray=[pboard propertyListForType:NSFilenamesPboardType];
      NSLog(@"fileArray:%@",fileArray);
    }
}

@end
```

We also have a services-Info.plist file...

```
    <key>NSServices</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>NSMenuItem</key>
        <dict>
            <key>default</key>
            <string>OpenDrive </string>
        </dict>
        <key>NSMessage</key>
        <string>handleServices</string>
        <key>NSPortName</key>
        <string>services</string>
        <key>NSSendTypes</key>
        <array>
            <string>NSFilenamesPboardType</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

We are able to add a single menu item to the Finder's contextual menu when right-clicking on a file.  Does anyone know of a way to add a sub-menu to this menu item?  I am unable to do it by modifying the plist file.  It has to be done programmatically using the Services API somehow... but I am unsure if this is supported to begin with.  I have looked at the 'Services Implementation Guide', however the solution isn't obvious to me.  The guide discusses adding Services to an application..  However I want to use Services to change the behavior of Finder which isn't my application..  Any guidance on this would be greatly appreciated.. Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'd love to have a few submenus on my NSService app option.